# Grails isn't saving domain classes in the propper database

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-2.0

I have a grails (2.0) application that needs to get certain information from multiple MySQL databases. I can't for the love of God get it to save the domain class in the proper database.

My Datasource.groovy File is something like this:

```
environments {
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "create-drop"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/informacion_empleados_dev"
    }
    dataSource_signOn {
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username = "root"
        password = ""
        dbCreate = "create-drop"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sign_on"
    }
    dataSource_administradores {
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username = "root"
        password = ""
        dbCreate = "create-drop"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/administradores"
    }
    dataSource_docentes {
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username = "root"
        password = ""
        dbCreate = "create-drop"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/docentes"
    }
    dataSource_alumnos {
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username = "root"
        password = ""
        dbCreate = "create-drop"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alumnos"
    }
}
```

And each of my domain classes references them as this

```
class Alumno {

static constraints = {      
    matricula   blank: false
    nombres     blank: false
    apellidos   blank: false
}

static mappings = {
    datasource  'alumnos'
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your domain class, it should be `mapping` not `mappings`

```
static mapping = {
    datasource  'alumnos'
}
```